# gpucoderSetup failed in MATLAB 2022a , passed in MATLAB 2021b

Tags: matlab, gpu

I check the cudnn&tensorrt environment of MATLAB GPU coder in MATLAB 2021b and MATLAB 2022a independently, MATLAB 2021b passed and MATLAB 2022a failed.
Here is the picture:
In MATLAB 2021b
[image]

while in MATLAB 2022a:
[image]

meanwhile, the Basic Code Generation failed too.
My two question is:

1. why cudnn&tensort was configured correctly in MATLAB2021b, while error occurs in MATLAB 2022A?
2. what is the proper reason that the Basic Code generation failed both in MATLAB 2022a and 2021b

here is my gpu configuration

```
                     Index: 1
         ComputeCapability: '8.6'
            SupportsDouble: 1
             DriverVersion: 11.6000
            ToolkitVersion: 11
        MaxThreadsPerBlock: 1024
          MaxShmemPerBlock: 49152
        MaxThreadBlockSize: [1024 1024 64]
               MaxGridSize: [2.1475e+09 65535 65535]
                 SIMDWidth: 32
               TotalMemory: 2.5769e+10
           AvailableMemory: 2.4283e+10
       MultiprocessorCount: 82
              ClockRateKHz: 1695000
               ComputeMode: 'Default'
      GPUOverlapsTransfers: 1
    KernelExecutionTimeout: 1
          CanMapHostMemory: 1
           DeviceSupported: 1
           DeviceAvailable: 1
            DeviceSelected: 1
```

Comment: Requirements do change occasionally with a new release of MATLAB. Maybe you need to update a driver or a compiler or something? Check the requirements!

Comment: Also, MinGW is mentioned there, which is incompatible with CUDA, so maybe there is some issue with the C++ compiler?

Comment: but I do have a visual studio 2019 and it works properly with MATLAB 2021b